# why bf1 and bf2 share a memory location, whereas bf3 and bf4 have its own memory location?

Tags: c++, memory

[image]

I found this picture in C++ concurrency in action page 105. the left side is a **struct**, the left side is a **memory model** of that **struct**. According to the book's description, **bf1** and **bf2** share a memory location, but **bf3** and **bf4** have its own memory location, which surprises me. the book does not explain the reason why they have such distinction. I want to know the reason why bf1 and bf2 share a memory location, whereas bf3 and bf4 have its own memory location?

Comment: I think the question is clear enough

Comment: This is implementation-defined. A compiler makes its own rules about how to lay out bit-fields in memory.  Include in the question which compiler this diagram is supposed to be for.  Another compiler might put all fiends in the same int.

Comment: This is likely not a very good example. I am very surprised that `bf1` and `bf2`, being of different types and a total of 35 bits in length, are supposed to share storage. If the next field (`bf3`) had been an *anonymous* field (`int : 0`), that would have asked the compiler to put the following fields in a new `int`. Now it is some compiler extension, at best. The standard doesn't have named zero sized fields.

Answer (score 3):

First you should understand what's mean of the memory location. I will show the specified reference C++ Standard **"A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having non-zero width."**. Then you can find the bf1 and bf2 are adjacent bit-fields, so they must belongs to the same memory location.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your citation really helps, but I don't understand why would someone define a bit-filed of zero width as bf3. Does it have some special meaning or usage?

Comment: @Sherwin Chen
 I show the other statements which copy from C++ Standard " As a special case, an unnamed bit-field with a width of zero specifies alignment of the next bit-field at an allocation unit boundary. Only when declaring an unnamed bit-field may the value of the constant-expression be equal to zero."